# why the command cd /xampp/htdocs/magento doesn't find file or directory?

Tags: magento, terminal

The goal is launching a setup:upgrade in Magento directory, but when I write cd `/xampp/htdocs/Magento` in my `terminal`, it gives a no such file or directory.

Comment: are you using lampp or xampp ? @flipps if lampp then check below :

cd /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento or /Magento whatever.

Comment: Hi @NikunjVadariya thanks for the answer, i use xampp, how can i do?

Comment: have switch current dictory to the directory where your xampp exits. I means if your Xampp is in D directory first from your terminal you need to open D drive then you can select this path

Comment: @Kul hi my xampp is in C directory, need i open the C directory too?

Comment: Yes.if you wanted to change the drive from “D:” to “C:”, you should type “c:” and then press Enter on your keyboard.

Comment: @Kul Now it works. Thanks.

Comment: Great. I'll make post it in answer and you can accept it as answer. so other people can benefit from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You have to switch current directory to the directory where your xampp
>   exits.

if your Xampp is in `D` directory. Then first from your terminal you need to open `D` drive.
if you wanted to change the drive from `C:` to `D:`, you should type “d:” and then press Enter on your keyboard.